# Jump table of function pointers indexed by char

Tags: c

I am writing a text editor where commands are executed according to the first character of the user's input.

For example, if the user enters `r filename.foo` the letter r will be used to call a `read_file()` function.  The obvious way to do this is to use a `switch(buf[0])` but I want to use an array of function pointers so I can say `(*fn[buf[0])` instead of writing out a long `switch` statement.  (For further clarification on this design pattern, see page 221 of Kernighan and Pike's "The Practice of Programming".)

I tried using an `enum` to associate each char with an integer, as `enum { 'r', 'w', 't', '\n' };` which would map 'r' to int 0, 'w' to int 1, 't', to int 2, and '\n' to int 3, but C doesn't allow chars to be used for that.  Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Could you provide some code (like when you tried to use an `enum`)?

Comment: @Erik W I tried to do something like this to map each char to consecutive integers:    
    
        `enum { 'r', 'w', 't', '\n' };`  
    
which would map 'r' to function 0, 'w' to function 1, 't', to function 2, and '\n' to function 3 of the function pointer table.

Comment: That is not how enums work. A correct one would look something like this: `enum Action { ACTION_READFILE = 'r', ACTION_WRITEFILE = 'w' };`

Comment: You could then say this: `void (*fn[])(void) = {[ACTION_READFILE] = read_file, [ACTION_WRITEFILE] = write_file };`

Comment: What's the problem with a `switch`? Your functions most likely don't take the same arguments anyway, do they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proper way in C to do this is to use designated initializers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void read(void)
{
    puts("read");
}

void write(void)
{
    puts("write");
}

typedef void (*function_map_t)(void);

function_map_t function_map[] = {
    ['r'] = read,
    ['w'] = write,
};
```

Use function_map[255] if you want to fix the size of the array. All missing entries are initialized with zero, as required by the standard.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html